# Drive JS API Realtime sample example is not behaving as expected

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Well i have just tried the sample example of real time js Google drive api. As they said in their tutorial,the application's text areas will be synced even if they are opened in different browser windows. But here the application is not doing that. It only reflects changes to the text areas of same browser window.

Here is the link: [Google Drive Realtime JS API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart)

Is there anything that i miss? I am running my application in Koding.com's vm.

Comment: Are you sure that both instances of the quickstart are on the same document?  Make sure the ids in the urls match.

Comment: Every time i run the application, it always creates separate "New Realtime Quickstart File" in google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the quickstart app with the base url will cause it to create a new document.

To view the same document twice, you can copy-paste the full url after its loaded, which should include a document id, or open an existing document from drive with your app.